# Is the declaration of an array of bools in C++ of size n guaranteed to be 0 for each arr[n]?

Tags: c++

If I declare an array of boolean variables in C++ like this:

```
bool someBooleans[MAX];
```

Is the value someBooleans[n] defined to be `0` for each n less than or equal to MAX by the standard ?

Or does it depend on the compiler ?

Comment: If it is in automatic storage, the elements are not initialized to any value, and it is undefined behaviour to read from them.

Comment: Is this in static storage at namespace scope, or does the variable have automatic storage duration?

Comment: what is meant by automatic storage ?

Comment: Automatic storage is what people often refer to as "the stack".

Comment: @NicholasM I am not allocating any memory for it if thats what you are asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, it is on the stack. Not the heap.

Comment: @Wildling, The heap is irrelevant. The choice is between automatic storage duration and static storage duration. Both are official terms that are easy to find more information about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all the valid range of indices is `0, MAX - 1`

If the array is defined outside any function that is if it has static storage duration then the Standard guarantees that all elements of  the array will be zero-initialized.
Otherwize the elements of the array are not initialized.

You could explicitly initialize its elements to zero (that corresponds to false) the following way

```
bool someBooleans[MAX] = {};
```

Comment: Ha! You edited the aggregate initializer in before I finished my answer. Deleted my answer and +1 :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal  Usually I write my answers before I will think about them.:) So I update very often my original answers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I read about storage durations from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). From what I understand a member variable of a class that is not declared `static` falls under automatic storage duration. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Wildling If a data member of a class is not declared as static then it has the same storage duration as the object of the class. Take into account that classes can have user defined constructors that can initialize data members of the class.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, but in order to know if the array would be zero initialized or not, I need to know if it has static storage or automatic storage. In this case i.e. when something has the same storage duration as its object, what is the storage class ? Static or automatic ?

Comment: @Wildling It is the object (that can consists from other subobjects) that has storage duration. And this object including its data members will be either initialized or not.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are traditionally 0 indexed. The declaration indicates the number of elements the array contains. So, to inspect the value of `someBooleans[i]`, `i` must be in the range of [0, MAX). A program is permitted to use `&someBooleans[MAX]` as well, but it is an error to read the value at that location.

If the array has static duration (by being global, scoped by a namespace, or the `static` storage class is specified) then it is initialized to all 0, and the contained elements will evaluate to `false`. Otherwise, the array is not initialized.

To initialize it to all 0 when declared as a local variable to a function:

```
bool someBooleans[MAX] = {};
```

To initialize it to all 0 when declared as a class member, you can use an empty initialization in the constructor to cause default initialization of the array:

```
class Foo {
    bool someBooleans[MAX];
    Foo () : someBooleans() {}
};
```

What you should probably use in C++ is `std::vector<bool>` instead. It will default initialize the elements for you:

```
std::vector<bool> someBooleans(MAX);
```

Using `std::vector<bool` has the advantage that it will provide a specialized version that is space optimized so that each boolean value is represented by a single bit.